# Привести запись из файла символов к записи в массив

Tags: java, io

Заданием было реализовать алгоритм сортировки TimSort, а так же реализовать считывание с файла, проведение сортировки считавшихся данных и обратная запись в файл. Каким образом мне правильно нужно записать в массив? В методе main после Scanner ругается IDE

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

// Java program to perform TimSort.
class GFG {

    static int MIN_MERGE = 32;

    public static int minRunLength(int n)
    {
        assert n >= 0;

        // Becomes 1 if any 1 bits are shifted off
        int r = 0;
        while (n >= MIN_MERGE)
        {
            r |= (n & 1);
            n >>= 1;
        }
        return n + r;
    }

    // This function sorts array from left index to
    // to right index which is of size atmost RUN
    public static void insertionSort(int[] arr, int left,
                                     int right)
    {
        for (int i = left + 1; i <= right; i++)
        {
            int temp = arr[i];
            int j = i - 1;
            while (j >= left && arr[j] > temp)
            {
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
                j--;
            }
            arr[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    }

    // Merge function merges the sorted runs
    public static void merge(int[] arr, int l,
                             int m, int r)
    {
        // Original array is broken in two parts
        // left and right array
        int len1 = m - l + 1, len2 = r - m;
        int[] left = new int[len1];
        int[] right = new int[len2];
        for (int x = 0; x < len1; x++)
        {
            left[x] = arr[l + x];
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < len2; x++)
        {
            right[x] = arr[m + 1 + x];
        }

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = l;

        // After comparing, we merge those two array
        // in larger sub array
        while (i < len1 && j < len2)
        {
            if (left[i] <= right[j])
            {
                arr[k] = left[i];
                i++;
            }
            else {
                arr[k] = right[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }

        // Copy remaining elements
        // of left, if any
        while (i < len1)
        {
            arr[k] = left[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }

        // Copy remaining element
        // of right, if any
        while (j < len2)
        {
            arr[k] = right[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }

    // Iterative Timsort function to sort the
    // array[0...n-1] (similar to merge sort)
    public static void timSort(int[] arr, int n)
    {
        int minRun = minRunLength(MIN_MERGE);

        // Sort individual subarrays of size RUN
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i += minRun)
        {
            insertionSort(arr, i,
                    Math.min((i + 31), (n - 1)));
        }

        // Start merging from size
        // RUN (or 32). It will
        // merge to form size 64,
        // then 128, 256 and so on
        // ....
        for (int size = minRun; size < n; size = 2 * size)
        {

            // Pick starting point
            // of left sub array. We
            // are going to merge
            // arr[left..left+size-1]
            // and arr[left+size, left+2*size-1]
            // After every merge, we
            // increase left by 2*size
            for (int left = 0; left < n;
                 left += 2 * size)
            {

                // Find ending point of left sub array
                // mid+1 is starting point of right sub
                // array
                int mid = left + size - 1;
                int right = Math.min((left + 2 * size - 1),
                        (n - 1));

                // Merge sub array arr[left.....mid] &
                // arr[mid+1....right]
                merge(arr, left, mid, right);
            }
        }
    }

    // Utility function to print the Array
    public static void printArray(int[] arr, int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        int[] arr = new int[];
        int n = arr.length;
        timSort(arr, n);

        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("text.txt"))) {
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                arr.add(scan.nextLine());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
            int size = input.available();

            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                System.out.print((char) input.read() + " "); // Чтение текстового файла посимвольно
                arr.add(char);
            }

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("file.txt"); // Создание текстового файла
            for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                output.write(arr[i]); // Запись каждого символа в текстовый файл
            }
            output.close();
        }catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.print("Exception");
        }

        System.out.println("Given Array is");
        printArray(arr, n);

        System.out.println("After Sorting Array is");
        printArray(arr, n);
    }
}
```

**UPD:** Числа во входном файле записаны в одну строку, разделены пробелом, диапазон 0 - 99999

Comment: Во первых у обычного `int[]` массива нет метода `add`. Во вторых, чего вы пытаетесь добиться, сортируя пустой массив в начале? И в третьих - напишите, как представлены данные в файле

Comment: @Стас, каким образом тогда добавить запись в массив?  Насчет данных - update сделал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это не алгоритмическая задача, то можно сделать при помощи стримов:

```java
int nums[] = Files
        .lines(Path.of("/path_to_file/nums.txt"))
        .flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s.split(" ")))
        .mapToInt(s -> Integer.valueOf(s))
        .toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Если коротко - вот:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 1) return;
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(args[0]))) {

            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
            while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                list.add(scan.nextInt());
            }

            System.out.println(list);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("File " + args[0] + " not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Так как количество чисел не известно заранее - используем `ArrayList`.

Объект `Scanner` я создаю в скобочках у блока `try`, чтобы задействовать [автоматическое управление ресурсами](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/703-java-7-try-with-resources).

Далее просто читаем файл и добавляем в `list`. Можно разделять числа не только пробелами, но и например, переносами строк, табами и т.д.

Comment: получается мне надо весь Тим сорт исправлять?